# como hacer que mi instalador/aplicacion arranque como servicio en c#?

Tags: c#

Bueno la cosa esque tengo un instalador en c# pero lo que necesito esque arranque como servicio. Bueno mi instalador es muy simple tal que así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Instalador
{
    [System.ComponentModel.RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Simple : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {

        Form4 form = new form4();
        public Simple()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Leí en varios artículos de la comunidad stackoverflow y mencionaban que era posible. Me refiero a este thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036713/automatically-start-a-windows-service-on-install

Entonces mi pregunta es posible que en mi instalador puede arrancarlo como servicio ya sea usando `OnBeforeInstall` o lo que sea necesario.
Alguien me puede aconsejar como poner mi instalador como servicio o que pasos debo tomar para ponerlo como servicio??

Podría ser algo así, tal como hicieron pero adaptado al formulario que debo usar?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Instalador
{
    [System.ComponentModel.RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Simple : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
    private readonly ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;
    private readonly System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

    Form4 form = new form4();
    public Simple()
    {

    }

    public ServiceInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();

        // Service will run under system account
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        // Service will have Start Type of Manual
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Windows Automatic Start Service";

        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        serviceInstaller.AfterInstall += ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall;            
    }
    private void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Windows Automatic Start Service");
        sc.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Has pensado en utilizar un instalador como InstallUtil?

Comment: si lo use pero no me arranca o el servicio una vez instalado no lo encuentro.

Comment: no lo encuentras? hombre, si lo has instalado y te indica que se ha instalado sin problemas lo tienes que tener en el panel de servicios. Asegúrate buscándolo con su nombre